# How can I package a relay (for lighting control)?

Tags: electrical, lighting, relay

Right now I have 3 high-pressure-sodium lights (475W actual x 3) on a single light switch.  It's a heavy duty switch, but these lights have magnetic ballasts (40 pound transformer) and they have a hell of an inductive kick.   I'd rather switch them with a relay.

Easy enough to find a bare component relay, but I don't have any idea how to package that into a Code-legal package.  Are there relays made for that purpose?

I know for instance that thermostat transformers are made which bolt into a 1/2" knockout, or serve as a lid to a junction box.  Does anything exist like that with relays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Someone already did all the work for you

Fortunately, you aren't the first person to run into this problem.  In fact, there have been enough people who have had this problem that the good folks at [Functional Devices](http://www.functionaldevices.com) slap an appropriate relay into an appropriate box, dress it up slightly, get it UL listed, and sell it!

In particular, you want something like a [RIB2401SB](http://functionaldevices.com/pdf/datasheets/RIB2401SB.pdf) for your job -- these are SPST-N/O relays rated for ballast loads up to 20A@277VAC, with a manual override switch and a multi-voltage coil that can run off 24VAC/DC or 120VAC. (A 208-277VAC version is also available.)